# Room Puzzle, containing chess and ciphers. Can someone help?

Tags: cipher, chess

[image]

**I Have to force checkmate black king in two moves only**
its white turn.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And the keypad**
[image]

Someone also asked this question here like a month ago, but the answer was wrong i tried alot of things but didnt work

Comment: Also note there's a [wiki page](https://udg-rbx.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_all_answers) available listing all the answers.

Comment: well, i tried that but it doesnt work, and the sign saying T=19 says "Here is the last five digit of the code but there are 4 openings, someone helped me at the cipher: a0z25 and it matches with T=19 maybe the openings you said could be wrong? idk

Comment: @Jafe leekage of the codes of rooms 225-250 are forbidden and they are not in wiki.

Comment: We shouldn't publish the answers here either, then.

Comment: @Jafe i just needed help tried alot but  doesnt work, im not like the people who just skip all the rooms i cant solve this room.

Comment: I understand, but this really is not the right forum I'm afraid. We have a policy about not allowing questions on ongoing competitions, and if the puzzle's publisher wants the codes to stay secret that's all the more reason to close this question as well as [Chess-based escape room](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109392/chess-based-escape-room), which I hadn't realised before was from an external source.

Comment: @Jafe https://udg-rbx.fandom.com/wiki/Facility_Headquarters asking anyone or getting help is not illegal as you can see here

Comment: @Jafe well atleast can you tell me what to exactly do? my brain really stops here

Comment: I really don't know, I thought I had the correct answer when the OP of the previous question checkmarked it but apparently not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mate in two:

> Rg8 Kxg8 
>  Qg7

So the vignere key is:

> Rookgeightqueengseven

Which decodes the ciphertext to:

> First and third digits are equal

The openings are:

> Amar opening, Queen's pawn opening, Englund gambit, Barnes opening

Which probably means:

> if T = 19 then A = 0, Q = 16, E = 4 and B = 1

Combining this with the decrypted text would lead me to believe the code is:

> 101641

Comment: oh also the sign that says T = 19 also says here are the first five digits but when we encode it, it gave only 4 digits so the openings could be wrong, if we could just find an opening that matches and also starts with 2 digit words (according to A0z25) maybe it would work cause itd give us 5 digits, but its just a theory idk alot about it

Comment: could it be latvian gambit?

Comment: Maybe 1. d4 d5 represents a Queen's pawn opening.  You can sub in a Q to get a six-digit code.

Comment: Thanks ALOT dude  the code is 101641, thanks for helping me i was trying to get this done for like 4 hours from now on

Comment: @SQLnoob please don't help people cheat.